# A generalized quadratic loss for deep neural network for multi-class classification

Tags: classification, learning

I'm evaluating the possibility to introduce a new loss for the subject described above.
Let $l$ be the number of examples, $q$ the number of classes,
 $p_{i,r}$ the $r$ classifier output on example $i$ and $y_{i,r}$ the binary indicator (0 or 1) if class label $r$ is the correct classification for the observation on pattern $i$. It would be: $\sum_{i=1}^{l} \sum_{j=1}^{l} (\sum_{r=1}^{q} y_{i,r} log(p_{i,r})) S_{i,j} (\sum_{r=1}^{q} y_{j,r} log(p_{j,r}))$
where the cross entropy loss is used and c.e. losses are correlated by a similarity matrix S positive semi definite.
There is any method to write this custom loss on a software framework for deep learning (e.g.: TensorFlow) and have a backtracking algorithm that is based on it?

Comment: Do $i$ and $j$ index over samples or over classes? I would guess the latter and your loss function is attempting to allow "fuzzy" classes where classes are similar?

Comment: Over samples, sorry.

Comment: I'm testing this loss with SVM, with S generated through a RBF kernel, and I get some results that are comparable to the linear loss.